# Applying subsurface modifier is making circular UV into starburst

Tags: modeling, modifiers, uv, subdivision-surface

[image]

I'm working on an air purifier which has power and other controls in the middle, I added a UV map to the model with the power button and other control icons, but when I add a subdivision modifier it makes a weird pattern, I'm new to blender this was my day 23 model not sure what to look for on google or the term to fix this.

I tried using the rounded cube, ico sphere, UV sphere and cylinder and still got the same result, tried adding more loop cuts, and indent.

without subdivision modifier
[image: without subdivision modifier]

with subdivision modifier
[image: with subdivision modifier]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add more geometry. Select the face and press <kbd>i</kbd> then move your mouse to inset the face which adds additional geometry.

[image]

The Subdivision Modifier is trying to convert the triangles at the central n-gon into quads and then [Catmull-Clark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catmull%E2%80%93Clark_subdivision_surface) algo does the "rounding" effect so you get this star effect. It needs to convert tris to quad so that it can be continuously subdivided when you add more levels of subdivision. By adding that additional geometry with an inset you get this result on the right:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, i would've gone another month without trying inset face this helped and the explanation helps more for future use.